# OpenCV cv::cvtColor drops alpha channel, How to keep alpha data?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, alpha, hsv

I have realized several things:

- that OpenCV does not handle alpha channels in `cvtColor(RGBAMat, HSVXMat, RGB2HSV, 4)` even though it silently accepts and ignores the 4 channel parameter and the 4 channel output matrix.
- that OpenCV does not convert datatypes in `cvtColor` though it happily accepts an output matix of different datatype from the input without warning.
- that OpenCV's `CV_AUTOSTEP` as the last parameter to `Mat(int h, int w, enum val DATATYPE, char* data, size_t step)` does **not work** when creating Mats from SDL_Surfaces. It causes segfaults that are remedied by using `surface->w * sizeof(whatever datatype the surface is)`.

Because of these realizations, I have accepted @ypnos answer since it is clearly on the right track. Be warned that none of the code on this page works as is.

```
void surface_change_sat(SDL_Surface* src_surf, SDL_Surface* dst_surf, float sat_diff) {
    using namespace cv;

    SDL_LockSurface(src_surf);
    Mat src_mat = Mat(src_surf->h, src_surf->w, CV_8UC4);                // Make mat from surf
    memcpy(src_mat.data, src_surf->pixels, src_surf->h * src_surf->w * sizeof(Uint32));
    SDL_UnlockSurface(src_surf);

    Mat src_rgbI = Mat(src_mat.rows, src_mat.cols, CV_8UC3);     // split rgba into rgb and a
    Mat aI_mat = Mat(src_mat.rows, src_mat.cols, CV_8UC1);       // since hsv has no a
    Mat to_ar[] {src_rgbI, aI_mat};
    int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };                      // r=0, ... a=3
    mixChannels(&src_mat, 1, to_ar, 2, from_to, 4);

    Mat rgbF_mat = Mat(src_mat.rows, src_mat.cols, CV_32FC3);    // Make ints into floats
    src_rgbI.convertTo(rgbF_mat, CV_32F);

    typedef Vec<float, 3> flt_vec_t;                             // The type of pixel in hsv
    Mat hsv_mat = Mat(src_mat.rows, src_mat.cols, CV_32FC3);
    cvtColor(rgbF_mat, hsv_mat, CV_RGB2HSV, 3);                  // convert to HSV

    flt_vec_t pix_vec;
    for (MatIterator_<flt_vec_t> mat_it = hsv_mat.begin<flt_vec_t>();
         mat_it != hsv_mat.end<flt_vec_t>();
         mat_it++) {
        pix_vec = *mat_it;
        Matx<float, 3, 1> pix_matx = (Matx<float, 3, 1>)pix_vec;
        CV_Assert(pix_matx.val[1] <= 1.0f && pix_matx.val[1] >= 0.0f);
        pix_matx.val[1] += sat_diff;
        if (pix_matx.val[1] > 1.0f) { pix_matx.val[1] = 1.0f; }
        if (pix_matx.val[1] < 0.0f) { pix_matx.val[1] = 0.0f; }
    }

    cvtColor(hsv_mat, rgbF_mat, CV_HSV2RGB, 3);              // convert back to RGB

    Mat dst_mat = Mat(dst_surf->h, dst_surf->w, CV_8UC4);
    Mat dst_rgbI = Mat(dst_mat.rows, dst_mat.cols, CV_8UC3);
    rgbF_mat.convertTo(dst_rgbI, CV_8U);                     // float back to int
    Mat from_ar[] {dst_rgbI, aI_mat};
    int to_from[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 0,3 };                  // r=0, ... a=3
    mixChannels(from_ar, 2, &dst_mat, 1, to_from, 4);        // add alpha for RGBA

    SDL_LockSurface(dst_surf);
    memcpy(dst_surf->pixels, (void*)dst_mat.data, dst_surf->h * dst_surf->w * sizeof(Uint32));
    SDL_UnlockSurface(dst_surf);
}
```

//-------------------Old Question -------------------------

I was getting the most mysterious memory errors until I added the `CV_Assert`s to the following function and realized that OpenCV was silently destroying the alpha channel in `cv::Mat hsv_mat`. I'm confused as to how to resolve this problem:One note, several other answers to related questions suggested thing like using shell scripts or cli tools like imagemagick. These are not helpful in this particular case. I need a standalone function with dependencies limited to opencv and the standard library.

**Note**: Following a suggestion in the comments, I explicitly split the alpha channel and converted from Uint8 to Float32. Now the assertions function, however, there is still a problem with invalid memory access causing a segfault.

Comment: Split the alpha into its own image, do the conversion, then join the result with the saved alpha. Sorry I don't know enough about OpenCV to give you exact steps.

Comment: I just tried that. Still somehow changes the fscking format of my cv::Mat without telling me at compile time or throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically cvtColor only works with a fixed set of matrix types, including the format and number of channels. So unmixing and remixing the channels is unavoidable.

The next thing I would do is use the templated data types. They give you a better understanding of what is held within a matrix, however sometimes OpenCV manages to violate that, too (at least in older versions).

This is how I would do it:

```
SDL_LockSurface(surf);
cv::Mat4b rgba(surf->h, surf->w, surf->pixels);
std::vector<cv::Mat1b> channels_rgba;
cv::split(rgba, channels_rgba);

// create matrix with first three channels only
std::vector<cv::Mat1b> channels_rgb(channels_rgba.begin(),
                                    channels_rgba.begin()+3);
cv::Mat3b rgb;
cv::merge(channels_rgb, rgb);

// create floating point representation
cv::Mat3f rgbhsv;
rgbhsv = rgb; // implicit conversion

// convert to HSV
cv::cvtColor(rgbhsv, rgbhsv, CV_RGB2HSV);

for (cv::Mat3f::iterator mat_it = rgbhsv.begin();
     mat_it != rgbhsv.end(); mat_it++) {
    cv::Vec3f &pix_vec = *mat_it;
    pix_vec[0] += hue_diff;
    if (pix_vec[0] >= 360.0f || pix_vec[0] < 0.0f) {
        pix_vec[0] = (180.0f / M_PI) * (std::asin(std::sin((pix_vec[0] * M_PI / 180.0f))));
    }
}

// convert back to RGB
cv::cvtColor(rgbhsv, rgbhsv, CV_HSV2RGB);

// back to unsigned char channels
rgb = rgbhsv; // implicit conversion
cv::split(rgb, channels_rgb);

// replace first three channels only
for (size_t i = 0; i < channels_rgb.size(); ++i)
    channels_rgba[i] = channels_rgb[i];

cv::merge(channels_rgba, rgba);
SDL_UnlockSurface(surf);
```

**Please note:**

1. I did not test this code!
2. It might be necessary to adjust data ranges (going back to convertTo() instead of assignment operator!
3. My last operation *may* not overwrite the surface data (you can go back to mixChannels which is known to not allocate any data ever)

Comment: Before I saw your answer, I came up with the changed code above. It, to my blind eye :), looks basically the same. The problem is that no matter what I try (like your except with mixChannel) or as above with the memcpys and separate output pointer, the output is always the same as the input! WTF am I missing?

Comment: Oh so if the output is the same as the input, it probably is because at some point new data is allocated. You can try this at the end instead: `cv::Mat4b dest(surf->h, surf->w, surf->pixels); rgba.copyTo(dest);` This should ensure that in fact surf->pixels gets overwritten.

Comment: That looks nice. I'm just curious as to why memcpy does not work.

Comment: Trying your suggestion without the memcpy leads to a segfault: `Thread [1] 23074 [core: 1] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault) 
 0x7ffff6fd12b8 
 cv::mixChannels() at 0x7ffff6fe72ec 
 surface_change_sat() at client.cpp:236 0x404a76 
 handle_mouse_motion() at client.cpp:427 0x403ba6 
 handler() at client.cpp:48 0x403608 
 main() at client.cpp:513 0x40703b 
`

Comment: A little more experimentation shows that any time that opencv tries to copy data from `void* src_surf->pixels` which is a pointer to Uint32[src_surf->h * src_surf->w], I get a segfault. Is this actually an SDL issue?

Comment: I didn't play with SDL surfaces yet, so I don't know what is going on there. Maybe you have to ensure that OpenCV uses a stepping of 0.